# Runtime Error due to NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios, core-data, runtime-error, dbcontext, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm stuck with this run time error which occurs 50% time while refreshing data or in splash (fetching from service and saving in coreData). I have looked through almost every solution on this problem but most of them were in Obj-C but I'm new to iOS and use swift. I have around 20 tables and all are using same context.

Below is my code:

```
public class ServiceCalls : NSManagedObject {
  /*
             class func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateMOC.parent = moc

        privateMOC.perform({
            do {
                try privateMOC.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        })
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
             */ // tried this but didn't work

     class func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
```

And this is how I'm using it, below is just one example of saving data in the database.

```
class func SaveCustomerContacts(name : String,id : String){

let context = getContext()
let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AllCustomerContacts_Tbl", in: context)
let newDoc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

newDoc.setValue(name, forKey: "contactName")
newDoc.setValue(id, forKey: "id") 



    //save the object
do {
    try context.save()
    print("saved Customer contacts in Database yayy!")

} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
} catch {
    let nserror = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
}
}
```

This is the complete exception being thrown:

```
    [error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2017-07-31 16:09:20.908 Sales CRM[5846:202190] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Do you have any fetchedResultsController setup? do you have any observers on NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification?

Comment: @JonRose No i'm not using NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification anywhere. and no fetchedResultsController setup as well.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Are you observing `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` anywhere? (2) What queue does this code run on?

Comment: @TomHarrington No i'm not using NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification anywhere in the code.

Comment: @TomHarrington i haven't mentioned any queue in my code, am i supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that some `nil` value is being inserted.

```
[error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2017-07-31 16:09:20.908 Sales CRM[5846:202190] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** First throw call stack:
```

There could be a number of reasons for this issue:

1. You are using multiple contexts and aren't handling them correctly.
2. You are trying to save a context with concurrency type `MainQueueConcurrencyType` in background. Use `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` instead.
3. The values being saved are `nil` or some sort of faulty data (in relations).

Comment: With your solution and this link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html i got this worked, Thanks Gp !

Comment: Amazing! Happy Coding :)